# What this java.lang.Throwable error in mongodb socket means?

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, glassfish

I trying to understand what is that error. It starts to happen when I put the mongoDB in another instance.

The error has a big message, but it doesn't say anything, and there's no action known which triggers it.

AT Tue Jan 12 19:34:31 UTC 2016
 BY :[java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1552), com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.done(ASURLClassLoader.java:216), com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.preDestroy(ASURLClassLoader.java:184), org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarClassLoader.preDestroy(EarClassLoader.java:114), org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.preDestroy(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:956), org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.preDestroy(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:940), org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.clean(ApplicationInfo.java:451), com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1071), com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1099), org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:412), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535), java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method), javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557), java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method), javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846), com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722), org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404), org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234), sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor419.invoke(Unknown Source), sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331), org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103), org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271), org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271), org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267), org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315), org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297), org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267), org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297), org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254), org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028), org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365), org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173), org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179), com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459), com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175), org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112), org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77), org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112), org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77), org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133), org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112), org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77), org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56), org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137), org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565), org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)] Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@7cbe8ac6
 was requested to find class org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext$1 after done was invoked from the following stack trace
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:825)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.(EncoderContext.java:27)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext$Builder.build(EncoderContext.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBody(CommandMessage.java:69)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:186)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

---

Error message image:

[image: error part 1]
[image]

---

Edit:

People from Payara Server [github issue](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/598) helped me to find the problem. I have used the ServletContextListener to kill the mongo connections before the deploy. Now, I'll wait some time to see if the problem is solved. Code bellow:

```
@Log
@WebListener
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Inject
    MongoClientProvider mongo;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg) {
        log.info("ServletContextListener destroyed");
        DbUtils.closeMongoConnections(mongo);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg) {
        log.info("ServletContextListener started");
    }
}
```

.

```
public class DbUtils {
    public static void closeMongoConnections(MongoClientProvider mongo) {
        mongo.getDeletedGroups().getManager().close();
        mongo.getMessages().getManager().close();
        mongo.getGameficationInfos().getManager().close();
        mongo.getDgsa().getManager().close();
        mongo.getRisa().getManager().close();
        mongo.getExpiredEmailLinks().getManager().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what JVM / JRE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You've chopped off the useful bit from the error, but it's present in your screenshot. There will be a bit before the `AT Tue Jan 12 19:34:31 UTC 2016` part as well which will tell you that the error is coming from the `ASURLClassLoader` telling you a bit about the state of the class loader.

The key part is the last line in the image:

```
...
was requested to find class org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext$1 after done was invoked from the following stack trace
```

The `done()` method that it's talking about is a cleanup method that is called when the classloader is ready to be garbage collected. So, at this point, the `EncoderContext` class is trying to load a class, but the `ASURLClassLoader` it reaches is in this kind of limbo state between being marked for cleanup, but not yet cleaned up.

I have seen a similar problem before, and I'm currently investigating it for Payara Server, which is derived from GlassFish. I would really appreciate it if you could raise an issue in the Payara Github repository:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues

T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶m̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶u̶g̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶G̶l̶a̶s̶s̶F̶i̶s̶h̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶P̶a̶y̶a̶r̶a̶ ̶S̶e̶r̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶r̶o̶p̶r̶i̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶i̶s̶c̶u̶s̶s̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶n̶g̶t̶h̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶Q̶&̶A̶ ̶s̶i̶t̶e̶!̶

---

**Edit:** Actually, looking closer at the `ASURLClassLoader` stack (the big screenshot) it looks like `done()` was called because of an undeployment. So it is probably that MongoDB was called from within an application that was undeployed and MongoDB was not disposed of at the same time.

This may have been what you wanted, but in that case, the MongoDB resource should not have been created from within the application. Otherwise, it needs to be destroyed properly before the application is undeployed.

Comment: Hum, I'l raise an issue there too. so, I can considere a Glassfish bug? The good/bad thing about this error is that doesn't makes any bad behavior in my application, it is a transparent error, which occurs always, but doesn't crash nothing

Comment: I've updated my answer. It looks like the actual problem here is that the application which launched MongoDB was undeployed, so MongoDB tries to reach its classloader, but finds that it's marked for removal. Because MongoDB still holds the reference to the classloader, it never gets garbage collected. To prevent the error, MongoDB must be disposed of before the application gets undeployed.

Comment: I'll add a new class in the question body, it's about my Singleton which inatances mongo connections

Comment: actually, what about I stop de mongo service before make the deploy. Would it kill any connection in database and solve the problem?